# How do i change the icon of a chrome window i run through vbs?

Tags: vbscript

So im currently trying to make a script that runs a specific website in application mode!

The only thing that i really want now, is for the website to also have another icon on the taskbar when launched.

Could i do this through VBS?

This is my current script:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" --app=https://faceit.com")
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\FACEIT AC\faceitclient.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I only want the chrome window that is launched to change icon. Not the "faceitclient.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Icons on the taskbar are property of the running processes. You can't change them with .vbs script. Only changing of .exe file resources could do this and it's pretty hard with vbs (if possible at all).